# Remove ୹ Character in String - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 7 columns, I am getting the value of the last column:

```
 var chkValue = $(this).closest('th').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').text();
```

For example the value is: "TEST"

When I try:

```
alert(chkValue);
```

return

```
୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹TEST୹୹୹୹୹୹୹
```

How I can remove this ୹ characters?

Comment: Can not read the character, its just ୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹TEST୹୹୹୹୹୹୹

Comment: Add your HTML also.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay  `if( chkValue == "TEST")` returns false

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Gislef Did you copy and paste the HTML which is rendering `"୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹TEST୹୹୹୹୹୹୹"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace characters that are not word characters. Though root issue appears to be the encoding of the `document`.

```
chkValue = chkValue.replace(/[^\w]/g, "");
```

Comment: for OP: **anything other than word, digit, whitespace will be removed, be informed**

Comment: @A.J OP hasn't mentioned this `anything other than word, digit, whitespace will be removed`

Comment: @A.J That is expected result based on text of original question, yes?

Comment: @gurvinder372 : Yes OP has not mentioned this, but I just explained the regex to OP,

Comment: @guest271314: Your answer is correct as per the question, I just wanted OP to know what regex will do .

Comment: @Gislef What is character encoding set to at text editor where HTML `document` was composed? Is `୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹TEST୹୹୹୹୹୹୹` expected to be rendered at HTML `document`?

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">` I had already inserted in my document, the problem does not seem to be this and text editor is configured with `coding utf-8 without BOM`. `chkValue = chkValue.replace(/[^\w]/g, "");` it´s work

Comment: Thanks @guest271314

Answer (score 1):

The replace is the way to go, but you have to know what characters are that...

I just wanted to give you a piece of advice, to simplifying your selection and make it independent of the number of cols (maybe in the future you have to add more columns and don't want to break this) you can use...

```
var chkValue = $(this).closest('th').children('td').last().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that what you see as `୹` are all the same characters (they may all look like squares but might be different unicode characters)

```
var myElement = $(this).closest('th').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td');
var newValue = myElement.text().replace('୹', '');
myElement.text( newValue );
```

Comment: I think it is a unicode, not sure it this function is fit. Anyway OP can clarify

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex

try this:

```
"୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹TEST୹୹୹୹୹".replace(/\W/g, '');
```

which \W is words and numbers

specifically for you add:

```
chkValue = chkValue.replace(/\W/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 then define charset. It might help you resolve the issue.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">` I had already inserted in my document, the problem does not seem to be this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var unicodeVal = "୹".charCodeAt(0); //get unicode value first

var output = "୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹TEST୹୹୹୹୹୹୹".replace( /./g, function(match)  { return match.charCodeAt(0) == unicodeVal ? "" : match } );

console.log( output );

//simpler approach if there is only one character to be replaced

output = "୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹୹TEST୹୹୹୹୹୹୹".replace( /./g, function(match)  { return match == "୹" ? "" : match } )

console.log( output );
```